poetry script containing a slash
I have a poetry script setup as follows:
[tool.poetry.scripts]
something = 'x.q.p:entrypoint'

What I'd like to do is be able to call the entrypoint by running something/blah
I tried
[tool.poetry.scripts]
"something/blah" = 'x.q.p:entrypoint'

but I get
Warning: The current project could not be installed: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/me/repos/something-blah/.venv/bin/something/blah'

The poetry docs are a bit light on this so I'm wondering what people would suggest to fix it?


What I'd like to do is be able to call the entrypoint by running something/blah

If the command contains a slash, the shell will assume it is a file in the current directory (as opposed to a command somewhere in $PATH), so you cannot have a command name with a slash in it.
in general, Command names are file names, and file names cannot contain slashes.
What you could do if you really want to run your command as something/blah is

make a directory called something
rename your command to something_blah in the poetry file
Create a file called something/blah that links to your command (for example containing the following)

#!/bin/bash
something_blah "$@"

But honestly, if your goal is to have a slash in your command name, I recommend against it.. Command names should not contain slashes, it's more of a hassle than it is worth

Got it,  do you know how to alias a folder in poetry so that something could reference something_blah?  then something/blah would translate to something_blah/blah

In poetry? I am talking about real folders in your current path dir.
If you want to "alias" those, you can make a symlink with ln -s something something_blah.
You would still need to create the something_blah folder.
